How do i open websites on my default chrome profile using Selenium? Chrome options keep on giving me an error
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
time.sleep(15)
driver.get("https://youtube.com")

I tried the above code, and it does open the chrome with my default profile. But it does not put in the link.
I have also tried using chrome_options=options, but chrome_options has gotten deprecated.
I expected chrome to open youtube in my default profile, but after opening the browser, nothing happens.

I believe you need to add another argument specifying the name of the profile, something like `options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=PROFILE_NAME'). Also -
This question is similar to: How to load default profile in Chrome using Python Selenium Webdriver?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No, i am able to open my default profile. like i said above too, but it just doesnt put in the website link in the searchbar, and searches for it. it's something related to driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options), it doesnt say what the error is though.
